# C programming / what is the difference between these two codes

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two codes?  I think it's same code.

It can't operate both of codeup and Visual Studio.
codeup.kr 1505 problem

The problem for array
when you put number it
it makes num*num array

For example, given num = 3, it creates:

```
1 2 3

8 9 4

7 6 5
```

Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
int tile[52][52];
int x, y;
int num;
int start = 1;
int check = 1, complete = 1;
int i;

scanf("%d", &num);
memset(tile, 0, 4 * 52 * 52);


tile[0][1] = 10;
tile[1][num + 1] = 10;
tile[num + 1][num + 1] = 10;
tile[num + 1][0] = 10;

x = 1; y = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= 3000; i++)
{
    switch (check)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        if (tile[x][y + 1] != 0)
        {

            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x][y++] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;

    }
    case 2:
    {
        if (tile[x + 1][y] != 0)
        {
            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x++][y] = start;
        start++;

        complete++;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if (tile[x][y - 1] != 0)
        {
            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x][y--] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        if (tile[x - 1][y] != 0)
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x--][y] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;
    }

    }
    if (complete == num*num)
    {
        break;
    }
}


if (num % 2 == 0)
{
    tile[x][y] = start;
}
else
{
    tile[x][y++] = start;
}


for (x = 1;x <= num; x++)
{
    for (y = 1; y <= num; y++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tile[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```

This code operates in Visual Studio.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{
int tile[52][52];
int x, y;
int num;
int start = 1;
int check = 1, complete = 1;
int i;

scanf("%d", &num);
for (x = 0;x <= num; x++)
{
    for (y = 0; y <= num; y++)
    {
        tile[x][y] = 0;
    }
}
tile[0][1] = 10;
tile[1][num+1] = 10;
tile[num + 1][num + 1] = 10;
tile[num + 1][0] = 10;

x = 1; y = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= 3000; i++)
{
    switch (check)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        if (tile[x][y + 1] != 0)
        {

            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x][y++] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;

    }
    case 2:
    {
        if (tile[x + 1][y] != 0)
        {
            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x++][y] = start;
        start++;

        complete++;
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        if (tile[x][y - 1] != 0)
        {
            check += 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x][y--] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        if (tile[x - 1][y] != 0)
        {
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
        tile[x--][y] = start;
        start++;
        complete++;
        break;
    }

    }
    if (complete == num*num)
    {
        break;
    }
}

if (num % 2 == 0)
{
    tile[x][y] = start;
}
else
{
    tile[x][y++] = start;
}


for (x = 1;x <= num; x++)
{
    for (y = 1; y <= num; y++)
    {
        printf("%d ", tile[x][y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference:

```
$ diff -w one.c two.c2,3d1

< #include<string.h>
< 
14,15c12,16
<   memset(tile, 0, 4 * 52 * 52);
< 
---
>   for (x = 0; x <= num; x++) {
>     for (y = 0; y <= num; y++) {
>       tile[x][y] = 0;
>     }
>   }
95a97
>
```

so, the first one uses memset to set **all** entries of `tile` to 0 (zero) and the second one uses a loop to set **only** the entries of `tile` to zero that are used, the content of the rest of the cells is undefined, could be everything. You can look for some places where `x` and/or `y` are outside of `0 <= x <= num < 52` in your code, or step through with a debugger, or use printf()s to find the exact places.

If you do not want to use `memset()` or are not able too: just change the loop to zero every cell out:

```
for (x = 0; x < 52; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < 52; y++) {
    tile[x][y] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice.